# Django: Password field "This field is required" error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I create a new model with additional fields for the `User`.

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        birthday = models.DateField(u'Birthday', blank=True, null=True)
        avatar = models.ImageField(Avatar', upload_to='profile/avatar', blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.user
```

Then I create registration form for users:

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
        username = forms.CharField(label=(u'Enter Your Username'))
        email = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Enter Your E-mail'))
        password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Enter Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
        password1 = forms.CharField(label=(u'Verify Your Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

        class Meta:
                model = UserProfile
                exclude = ('user',)

        def clean_email(self):
                email = self.cleaned_data['email']
                try:
                        User.objects.get(email=email)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                        return email
                raise forms.ValidationError("User with same e-mail is already exist, please type another email")

        def clean_password(self):
                password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
                password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')

                if not password1:
                        raise forms.ValidationError("You have ti verify your password")
                if password != password1:
                        raise forms.ValidationError("Your passwords doesn't match")
                return password1
```

And this is my view for registration page:

```
def UserProfileRegistration(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/info/')
        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
                        user.save()
                        user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
                        user_profile.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/info/')
                else:
                        return render(request, 'profiles/registration.html', {'form':form})
        else:
                form = RegistrationForm()
                context = {'form':form}
                return render (request, 'profiles/registration.html', context)
```

And there is how looks like my html page:

```
 <form action="." method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {% if form.username.errors %}
    {% for error in form.username.errors %}
       <p>This field is required</p>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
 {{ form.username.label_tag}}
 {{ form.username }}
 {% if form.email.errors %}
    {% for error in form.email.errors %}
       <p>This field is required</p>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
 {{ form.email.label_tag }}
 {{ form.email }}
 {% if form.password.errors %}
    {% for error in form.password.errors %}
       <p>This field is required</p>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
 {{ form.password.label_tag }}
 {{ form.password }}
 {% if form.password1.errors %}
    {% for error in form.password1.errors %}
       <p>This field is required</p>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
 {{ form.password1.label_tag }}
 {{ form.password1 }}
 </form>
```

But when I try to register user, I have the error

> This field is required

for the `password` field. I can't understand why.

I would be glad if you help me with that.

Comment: Instead of `<p>This field is required</p>` try `<p>{{ error }}</p>`

Comment: Thank you. For your comment. Now I understand what happening

Comment: You can replace your comment in to the answer.

Comment: And what was happening?

Comment: in forms.py i change `password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')  password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')`, to `password = self.cleaned_data['password']  password1 = self.cleaned_data.['password1']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of print predefind error message try to print real error message.

Instead of

```
<p>This field is required</p>
```

use

```
<p>{{ error }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your clean_password method you are returning password1 after validation. You should return password object instead. For model forms this is important.

When saving the model, form field names are used to decide which model field is which form field.